# Is it possible to use the USB port of the host PC in Window CE 6.0 emulator?

Tags: usb, windows-ce, emulation

I would need to use the USB port of the host PC in Windows CE 6.0 R3 emulator.

Is this possible? or is there any kind of workarround?

I would like to test my application without having my target, just the USB peripheral that would be attached to my laptop PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid not.  Most PC hardware is not supported inside the emulator.

[This link explaining the limitations of the WinCE emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms925013.aspx) is for CE.net (4.x) but should still apply to the later emulators.

You'll have to run on the real hardware.   You should be able to setup a ActiveSync based debugging session however.

Comment: Unfortunately you are right :( it is official, thnx for the link.